# Importing Excel / XLS into SSIS?

Tags: ssis, import, excel-2007, excel-2003, xls

Tips, Tricks, Pitfalls & Best Practice please:

in other words
e.g.

Do use this connection
Don't use this datatype
Do sort X
Don't open over network
Z gets corrupted when Q is likely
Don't use "," use "|" as separator
Don't use 'wizard' that determines column datatype by sampling n rows
Don't use multiple sheet

(the above list is not meant to be a guide, just me thinking of random stuff!)

Answer (score 0):

There are some Excel connection managers on [codeplex](http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/).  Running on a 64 server needs to use the 32 bit DTEXEC.  Looks like they have a 64 bit provider, but it's for sale from CozyRoc.  There is the Excel2 manager also, which looks free.

Comment: Q. What do these add above and beyond the 'normal' connections? I had a look at codeplex but couldn't see why it was better (excluding any 64bit functionality)?

Answer (score 0):

You are right about column datatypes and problems with row samplings.

Sometimes it's easier to save the Excel file to CSV and import that.